# Unity 2D transform particle system

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, system, particles

I'm trying to figure out how position an explosion created with the Unity particle system. The explosion should happen where a bomb collides with a box collider. I am not having much luck with the C# script. Any advice is appreciated. Code snippet listed below. xPos and yPos are declared as floats.

```
   // This part works.
    xPos = collisionObject.transform.position.x;
    yPos = collisionObject.transform.position.y;

    // This part generates an error.
    explosionContainer.transform.position.x = xPos;
    explosionContainer.transform.position.y = ypos;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

This happens because `Transform.position` is a property of type `Vector3` which is a struct. Structures in C# is a value types. What happens here:

1. Since structs are value types `collisionObject.transform.position` returns you a copy of some `Vector3`
2. By doing `.x = xPos` you are trying to modify `x` member of this copy of some `Vector3` struct. This copy is going to be discarded instantly. Thus your assignment is useless. This is why compiler gives you an error.

## Solution

If you want assign a new value to `Transform.position` you need to do it as follows:

```
Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(xPos, yPos);
explosionContainer.transform.position = newPosition;
```

Alternatively, you can use `Transform.Translate` method as Daniel has pointed out.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks. I'll put this one in my notes.

Answer (score 0):

instead of trying to set the `.x` or `.y` parts of the position, use `Transform.translate`. I believe that will move the explosion relative to where it already is (it will shift it by X, not jump to X) but if you instantiate the object at 0,0, it should act the same.

```
explosionContainer.Transform.translate(new Vector2D(xPos, yPos));
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. With a minor change, I got it to work with: explosionContainer.transform.Translate(new Vector2(xPos, yPos));